# Creating tracks for moving points (while discarding records without movement)

Tags: qgis, point, path, movement-data, aggregate

I have a csv with columns:

| id | latitude | longitude | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

Many of the points (or `"id"`s) do not change `"latitude"`/`"longitude"` over time, others do.

How do I filter out those `"id"`s and `"lat"`/`"long"`s for the ones that did not move?

For the `"id"`s that do move, there's a path. How do I export or select only the paths or the `"lat"`/`"long"`s of those ids that moved?

Is this possible with MMQGIS or another time-series Plugin?

Comment: I would suggest Python for this. You could save a copy of the CSV for the sake of comparing old state and new state. Then convert CSV in Python dictionary for example, and then just compare these two. Then get rows that are different do whatever you need with them.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Aggregate`. In the field `Group by expression (NULL to group all features)` set this expression `"id" || "latitude" || "longitude"` (replace `id` `latitude` and `longitude` with the exact names of your fields) and decide for each of the fields how they should be aggregated. For id, latitude and longitude, you can select `first value`, for timestamp (and other fields, if you have) you should decide which one you want to keep: all others will be deleted.

In fact you create one feature from several features each time the combination (concatenated text string) of id, latitude and longitue is the same, thus when the same item is in the same place.

[image]